# Array methods exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help for this exercise:

Array methods

Implement the `uncompletedNotes` function which, given an array of notes, returns only the uncompleted notes. A note is considered completed if all todo present have the done flag set to true.

This is what I've done:

```js
function uncompletedNotes(notes) {

  let result = []

  notes.forEach(element => {
    if (element.todos.done == false) {
      result.push(element);
    }
  });

  return result;

}

const notes = [{
    id: 1,
    description: 'Workout program',
    todos: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Push ups - 10 x 3',
        done: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Abdominals - 20 x 3',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Tapis Roulant - 15min',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: 'Front-end Roadmap',
    todos: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Learn HTML',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Learn CSS',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Learn JavaScript',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Learn Angular',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  }
]

const notesInProgress = uncompletedNotes(notes);
console.log('All notes: ', notes);
console.log('Notes In Progress: ', notesInProgress);
```

But it gives me an empty array result in Notes in Progress.

Comment: This should help, please try: `notes.filter(n => n.todos.some(t => (t.done === false)));`. Iterates over `notes` & finds `some` element in `todos` which has `done` set to false. Instead of `t.done === false`, one may also use !t.done.

Answer (score 5):

```
function uncompletedNotes(notes) {
    return notes.filter(note => note.todos.filter(todo => !todo.done))
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for the inner `filter` to be `some`? That way we can stop after the first and it doesn't need to build the resulting array for the inner call.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, `some` can be used to optimize the execution.

Comment: `find` should also work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the `todos` property of each notes is itself an array, ie there is no `done` property on `todos`. It may be useful to look at the array methods `every` or `some` (likely `some`), which will return true if any item in an iterable returns true for a given condition.

```js
 function uncompletedNotes(notes) {
  
  let result = []
      
      notes.forEach(element => {
        if(element.todos.some(todo => todo.done === false)) {
          result.push(element);
        }
      });

   return result;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Todos is also an array, so you'd have to iterate over that one as well

Answer (score 0):

'todos' is an array as well. You need to iterate over it. One way to do that is to use the [`find` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as shown below.

```js
function uncompletedNotes(notes) {
  
  let result = []
  
  notes.forEach(element => {
    if(element.todos.find(todo => todo.done === false)) {
      result.push(element);
    }
  });

  return result;

}

const notes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    description: 'Workout program',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Push ups - 10 x 3',
        done: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Abdominals - 20 x 3',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Tapis Roulant - 15min',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: 'Front-end Roadmap',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Learn HTML',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Learn CSS',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Learn JavaScript',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Learn Angular',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  }
]

const notesInProgress = uncompletedNotes(notes);
console.log('All notes: ', notes);
console.log('Notes In Progress: ', notesInProgress);
```

Answer (score 0):

For each notes iterate over the todos

- for each todos

  - check if its `'done'==true`
  - if all the 'done's are not true, then push the note  to inProgress array.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly! Nice exercise. Second i change only a little bit in you foreach loop. And use filter.

```
  notes.forEach(element => {
    const open = element.todos.filter(t => t.done === false)    
    result.push(...open)
  });
```

```js
function uncompletedNotes(notes) {
  
  let result = []
  
  notes.forEach(element => {
    const open = element.todos.filter(t => t.done === false)    
    result.push(...open)
  });
  return result;
}

const notes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    description: 'Workout program',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Push ups - 10 x 3',
        done: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Abdominals - 20 x 3',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Tapis Roulant - 15min',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: 'Front-end Roadmap',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Learn HTML',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Learn CSS',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Learn JavaScript',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Learn Angular',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  }
]

const notesInProgress = uncompletedNotes(notes);
console.log('All notes: ', notes);
console.log('Notes In Progress: ', notesInProgress);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop, you have this line:

```js
if(element.todos.done == false) {
```

Since `todos` is an array, you would need to check whether any of the array todos have their `done` property set to false. There are a few ways you can do this, but the way I've implemented in the full code at the end is using the [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
    let todos = element.todos.filter(todo => !todo.done);
    // If todos contains at least one task, it is incomplete...
    if (todos.length > 0) {
      // ... so add it to the result array (which we return shortly)
      result.push(element);
    }
```

See the full code below for example:

```js
function uncompletedNotes(notes) {
  let result = []
  notes.forEach(element => {
    let todos = element.todos.filter(todo => !todo.done);
    if (todos.length > 0) {
      result.push(element);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

const notes = [{
    id: 1,
    description: 'Workout program',
    todos: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Push ups - 10 x 3',
        done: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Abdominals - 20 x 3',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Tapis Roulant - 15min',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: 'Front-end Roadmap',
    todos: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Learn HTML',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Learn CSS',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Learn JavaScript',
        done: true
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Learn Angular',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  }
]

const notesInProgress = uncompletedNotes(notes);
console.log('All notes:', notes);
console.log('Notes In Progress:', notesInProgress);
```